# Copying an array of sheets vba

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to copy a bunch of sheets from a template file to a new file, but this was resulting in the formulas referring to the original template- so I saw online that I should use an array- but now getting a "Subscript out of range" error. What am I doing wrong-it errors on the last line? Also i tried ws() as string and that did not work either.

```
Dim templateworkbookname As string
templateworkbookname="test.xlsx"
Dim ws() As Variant   
        Dim j As Integer
        ReDim ws(Workbooks(templateworkbookname).Worksheets.Count)
        For j = 1 To Workbooks(templateworkbookname).Worksheets.Count
                ws(j) = Workbooks(templateworkbookname).Worksheets(j).Name
        Next
        Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
        Workbooks(templateworkbookname).Worksheets(ws).Copy Before:=newbook.Sheets(1)
```

Comment: Is this your full code?  It looks like `templateworkbookname` is not defined, which would raise a `Subscript out of range` error.

Comment: No, it's not the full code, but it is defined (edited it now)

Comment: s/defined/**assigned**. and that should really be a `String`, not a `Variant`.

Comment: @Mat's Mug changed, but the sheet copying still doesn't work

Comment: I am not sure why your doing this, if you are just copying all the sheets to a new workbook, why not just save the original workbook as a new name?

Comment: Well I'm doing it multiple times. I figure it's faster than opening/ reopening? Not sure. Even if not it may end up being a subset of sheets in the future so I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code around a bit because this seemed like what you wanted to accomplish. If you have a new, blank Workbook open, then this will open the `test.xlsx` one, then copy in the sheets, then close it, and your blank workbook will now have the 3 sheets from `test.xlsx` in it. Note that I had to provide the entire path to `test.xlsx` so it could find it.

```
Set currentworkbook = ActiveSheet
Dim templateworkbookname as String
templateworkbookname = "c:\test.xlsx"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(templateworkbookname)

Dim ws() As Variant
Dim j As Integer
ReDim ws(wb.Worksheets.Count)
For j = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
    ws(j) = wb.Worksheets(j).Name
Next

For j = 1 To UBound(ws)
    wb.Worksheets(j).Copy Before:=currentworkbook
Next

wb.Close
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but I'm putting all of this in a loop to do it multiple times, and at some point this will be part of an addin. So I need the main macro to call the template workbook and then add another for it to save to